# postfixs email rejected with forged ehlo/helo error 550

Tags: debian, postfix

i have multiple ip addresses and domains and configured postfix to use the correct ip address according to the sender-address using a map

now there are still servers answering with a forged 550 but i can't determine why? from what i can see from the logs and email headers the correct ip and domain are being used.

excerpt from master.cf:

```
example-sender-org unix - - - - - smtp -v
        -o smtp_bind_address=11.x.x.x
        -o smtp_helo_name=example-sender.org
        -o syslog_name=postfix-example-sender-org
```

Example E-Mail Header:

```
Received: from example-sender.org (example-sender.org [11.x.x.x])
```

Example postfix debug log (smtp -v):

```
deliver_message: from sender@example-sender.org
smtp_parse_destination: example-recipient.org smtp
connecting to example-recipient.org port 25
dns_query: example-recipient.org (MX): OK
dns_get_answer: type MX for example-recipient.org
smtp_addr_one: host mx0.example-recipient.org
lookup mx0.example-recipient.org type A flags 128
dns_query: mx0.example-recipient.org (A): OK
dns_get_answer: type A for mx0.example-recipient.org
begin example-recipient.org address list
pref   50 host mx0.example-recipient.org/10.x.x.x
end example-recipient.org address list
smtp_find_self: not found
smtp_connect_addr: bind 11.x.x.x
smtp_connect_addr: trying: mx0.example-recipient.org[10.x.x.x] port 25...
vstream_tweak_tcp: TCP_MAXSEG 1448
global TLS level: none
< mx0.example-recipient.org[11.x.x.x]:25: 220 mx0.some-hoster-example.org ESMTP (some-other-domain.org) (even more power) Tue, 15 Oct 2013 12:
> mx0.example-recipient.org[11.x.x.x]:25: EHLO example-sender.org
< mx0.example-recipient.org[11.x.x.x]:25: 550-Forged HELO: You are not example-sender.org, please use sender
< mx0.example-recipient.org[11.x.x.x]:25: 550 domain as HELO/EHLO not recipient domain.
> mx0.example-recipient.org[11.x.x.x]:25: HELO example-sender.org
< mx0.example-recipient.org[11.x.x.x]:25: 550-Forged HELO: You are not example-sender.org, please use sender
< mx0.example-recipient.org[11.x.x.x]:25: 550 domain as HELO/EHLO not recipient domain.
```

side note: my mx0 for the sender domain does not point to the same ip address... is it possible that thats the problem? i assumed the a-record was required...

i found this (third answer):
http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/228915-exchange-2007-error-550-5-7-1-helo-and-dns-mx-settings

Comment: just a note: i did this test and the helo/ehlo section was ok http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test/

Comment: another note: having multiple domains but less ip addresses, if i want to send emails via all domains, then the helo/ehlo check effectively forces me to have a ip address per domain, because otherwise i can never make sure that mx0, sender-domain and reverse dns are matching.

Answer (score 0):

turns out the hoster requires you to use your mx0 as heloname, all other are discarded...